# Exception in PDO PHP doesn't work

Tags: php, pdo, exception

I just created lines of code to insert some data to database using PDO with MySQL database.
The code is the following :

```
define("cstring", "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=perpus2014");
define("username", "root");
define("password", "");

class database {
    protected $koneksi;
    protected function db() {
        try {
            $koneksi = new PDO(cstring, username, password);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getmessage();
        }
        return $koneksi;
    }
}

//------------------------------------

class adm extends database {
    private $nama;
    private $password;
    private $conn;

    function __construct() {
        $this->conn = $this->db();
    }

    function set($value1, $value2) {
        $this->nama = $value1;
        $this->password = $value2;
    }

    private function getname() {
        return $this->nama;
    }

    private function getpass() {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function insert() {
        try {
            $save = $this->conn->prepare("insert intdo tes (nama,password) values (?,?)");
            $save->bindParam(1, $this->getname());
            $save->bindParam(2, $this->getpass());
            $save->execute();
            return true;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            print $e->getMessage();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The code has succesfully inserted rows to database, but when I tried to miss-spelling the code like "bindParam" to "blindParam" or "insert" to "insseert" or whatever, the code kept giving 1 as boolean return after $save->execute();

what's wrong with my exception, why didn't it print error message and return false boolean?

Updated, I posted the complete code.

Comment: Because running not existing method is a php fatal error, it has nothing to do with `PDOException`

Comment: I had changed PDOException to exception, still didn't work.

Comment: In what kinds of error that PDOException will work?

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to make sure, that PDO throws an exception, when something bad happens, make sure, to set your error mode to exception, in your case:  `$koneksi->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`
2. In the constructor of your `database` class you might fail to create a `database` object and return `null`. In my opinion, if an error occurs, it shouldn't be handled there.
3. If you call non-existing methods on an object, then it's not the objects responsibility to handle the error it's the interpreters. If the `PDO` class doesn't have an `inseeert` method, how should it be responsible for producing an error, if you try to call that? `PDOException`s are only raised, if there is an error in your database code, eg.: connection fails, syntax error in your query, etc...

**Update**: For the third suggestion:

```
$pdo = new PDO( /* params here */ );
$pdo->query('SELECT * FROM test');
```

In the above case the error will be raised by the interpreter, because the PDO class doesn't have a query method.

```
$pdo->query('SLECT * FROM test');
```

Now here the PDO class can raise an Exception, because your code (from PHP perspective) is correct, but you supplied a wrong parameter (a query string with bad syntax).

I hope it helps. Also please read about [`Exceptions`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php), if it's still unclear, what they can be used for.

Comment: I did the first suggestion, adding $koneksi->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
I found that It caused the problem why exception didn't work.

I don't really understand the third suggestion, could you give me example? Thanks before, I'm newbie.